# golang - reuse previously built executables if code did not change

Tags: go, build

I have a pretty big golang project that produces several executables,
when I update my code I want an easy and fast way to rebuild all of them
however it takes ~20-25 sec to build all of them and most of the time I change just 1 or 2

The ultimate goal - detect what changed and rebuild only changed targets as fast as possible(CI)

p.s. some parts of project use cgo, and this takes the 40-50% of the build time

Comment: How are you building your executables? This is exactly what `go install` does.

Comment: Are you attempting to reuse C code that's been built previously but has not changed?

Comment: I'm building simply by invoking `go build`. Regarding reusing C code - I'm not sure, program is being statically linked with v8 js engine and some glue c++ code on top of it which is exported via cgo interface. Thanks for `go install` going to check this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the top level of your project

```
go install ./...
```

Should install all the binaries into $GOPATH/bin

`go install` caches the build artifacts (unlike `go build`) so should do incremental builds exactly as you want.

Comment: is there any easy way to check if the build required without actually making it?

Comment: found it! just run `go install -n ...` and check for command stdout

Comment: This does not work for me (with go v1.11.5 on Debian9). Both go build and go install always rebuild (or at least touch the final image).

Comment: To clarify go build and go install always touch the executable giving it a new time-stamp though the md5sum may be identical.

Comment: This works less well when cross-compiling for various architectures, as you cannot specify GOBIN without errors, and you cannot use -o as you would with `go build`.